# GIF transparent background turned to black

Tags: php, gd, gif

I have a script that resizes uploaded images. It works fine for PNGs and JPGs but with GIFs it renders the transparency in the resized GIF black.

```
    $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height); 
    imagegif($dst, $file);
```

Comment: Just search *"php imagecopyresampled transparent gif"*. Lots of results, some even on the manual page

Answer (score 4):

From the manual page https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php#104028

```
imagecolortransparent($new, imagecolorallocatealpha($new, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagealphablending($new, false);
imagesavealpha($new, true);
```

is used by one poster to preserve transparency.

Here's a tip... Always check out user comments on php.net as they are generally very helpful in understanding the nuances of a function and providing tips for handling common tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this goes to a web-page, which if it does you could just output the image tag with the correct attributes?

```
echo "<img src='$file' width='$newWidth' height='$newHeight' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You still have to set the transparency in the new image. The following is taken from the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php):

```
<?php
// Create a 55x30 image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(55, 30);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

// Make the background transparent
imagecolortransparent($im, $black);
// ^^ This is the command you are missing.

// Draw a red rectangle
imagefilledrectangle($im, 4, 4, 50, 25, $red);

// Save the image
imagepng($im, './imagecolortransparent.png');
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

In your case, you want to make the transparency the same color as the original transaprency - which I always made a hideous purple or something that would a) stick out like a sore thumb in my image manipulation software and secondly, have a RGB key that was almost impossible to have included in an image by mistake.